# Relative Imports in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have an import which looks like this

`import Button from "../../../components/Button/Button"`

but I want to make it relative so I wouldn't require to type the `../../../` time and again.

I want to import using  this method:

`import Button from "components/Button/Button"` or `src/components/Button/Button`

but please also assure that it will work on **both production and development.**

Comment: If you're using webpack you can create an alias for  the `./components/` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vscode with project created with create-react-app you can try adding a jsconfig.json file in root with this .

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "src"
  },
 "include": ["src"]
 }
```

Comment: That's only sufficient for IDE tooling. You also need to configure whatever loader/bundler is being used

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks, I updated it for a very specific case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/). You can use resolve.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/'),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
    }
  }
};
```

Now, instead of using relative paths when importing like so:

```
import Utility from '../../utilities/utility';
import Button from '../../src/components/Button';
```

you can use the alias:

```
import Utility from 'Utilities/utility';
import Button from 'Components/Button';
```

Answer (score -1):

you can download the react snippet plugig to help you with import

*import Butoon from './component/Button/Button'*  I Think